# Full browser-screen DIV injected to body element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been asked to create a script that can be applied to any site. I've used google results page as a test.

All I want is a full screen semi-transparent div on any site. It's for cookie notification.

So i've added this to the results page:

```
 <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1;  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; left:0px;  opacity:0.5; background-color:blue;"></div>
```

before end of "body" element.

The google logo and search div takes precedent. And i get...
[image]

Comment: add top:0 ..... and you will have more chance with `position:fixed`

Comment: position fixed ans z-index worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of z-index, use `z-index:200` .

```
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:200;  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; left:0px;  opacity:0.5; background-color:blue;"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not using `z-index: 199;` or `z-index: 201;` ? I mean, answers with 'use this', 'try this' ... don't help anyone, we have to provide explanations. Thanks for your comprehension.

Comment: position fixed with a high z-index worked. Thank you

Comment: @NishantDixit but we DON'T only give an answer to the OP, we give answers to the community not specifically to a person by itself, like so we reassure that the benefits of the answers will be shared among many and many visitors/members or even those who just need some specific answers that doesn't require them to create accounts... Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

To make the script work not only on Google, but on all other web pages and in any browser, set `z-index` to `2147483647`.

```
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:2147483647;  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; left:0px;  opacity:0.5; background-color:blue;"></div>
```

This places your div over every other element in the DOM.